# Python: print out all values of a complicated data structure (excluding hash keys)

Tags: python, list, recursion, dictionary

Basically, I have a very lengthy and complicated data structure. To simplify, it basically looks like this:

```
{'tom':'stats', 'keys':[{'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999},{'mum':'veg', 'nba':'qweqwe'}] }
```

It is a dictionary with string values and integer values. However, sometimes the value can be a `list` and that list can contain dictionaries.

I want to write a function that recursively prints out everything in the data structure. Can someone show me how this can be done?

**EDIT**
Sorry. I didn't explain the question properly. I know I can use `pprint` and `json` to print it out nicely. But this is not what I want. 
I want the output to look like this:
`stats, doc,1999, veg , qweqwe`

An example of complicated data structure that I am working with would look like :

`{'edw': {'_tot': 1, 'val': [{'sd': {'yr': 93}, 'Date': {'r': 19}, 'deg': 'B', 'skl': 'Uni', 'field': 'sports', 'phonenum': 5121123}]}}`

**UPDATE**

Thank you very much for all your great answers guys! I really learned a lot.

Comment: `from pprint import pprint`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to show you teh codez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {'tom':'stats', 'keys':[{'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999},{'mum':'veg', 'nba':'qweqwe'}] }

def print_all_values(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        for key, value in input.items():
            print_all_values(value)
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        for value in input:
            print_all_values(value)
    else:
        print(input)

print_all_values(d)
```

Comment: What if I want to store all the values in a list ? How would I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to beat using [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to do this:

```
rd={'tom':'stats'  , 'keys':[{'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999},{'mum':'veg', 'nba':'qweqwe'}] }

import json
print json.dumps(rd, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "tim": "doc", 
            "year": 1999
        }, 
        {
            "mum": "veg", 
            "nba": "qweqwe"
        }
    ], 
    "tom": "stats"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return a list of all values presuming your actual dicts follow the same format:

```
def get_vals(items):
    final=[]
    for elem in items.itervalues():
        if isinstance(elem, dict):
            final += elem.values()
        elif isinstance(elem, list):
            for sub_elem in elem:
                    final += sub_elem.values()
        else:
            final.append(elem)
    return final


print (get_vals(d))
['doc', 1999, 'veg', 'qweqwe', 'stats']
```

Try this on your more complicated structure:

```
def flatten(items):
    final = []
    if isinstance(items, dict):
        for val in items.itervalues():
            final += flatten(val)
    elif isinstance(items, list):
        for elem in items:
            final += flatten(elem)
    else:
        final.append(items)
    return final
```

Comment: your function doesn't print anything except `None`. Would highly appreciate if it can store all the values in a list.

Comment: @Chinegro,I forgot the return statement, it will print the list of values now

Comment: your code only works for the toy example I specified above, I am actually dealing with very complicated data structure. And it doesn't use recursion

Comment: well post an example of your more complicated data structure and I will adapt the code and my code works for any dict with lists of dicts inside.

Comment: Sorry, it took me quite a while to create the data structure....

Comment: No worries, I will put a new answer up later when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the output mirrors the order of the original data. I'll leave it to you come up a sort :-)

```
import inspect

def extractValuesFromList(results_,list_):

    for item_ in list_:
        print '%s %s %s' % (inspect.stack()[0][3],type(item_),item_)
        if type(item_) == list:
            extractValuesFromList(results_,item_)
        elif type(item_) == dict:
            extractValuesFromDictionary(results_,item_)

def extractValuesFromDictionary(results_,dict_):

    for key_ in dict_.keys():
        value_ = dict_[key_]
        print '%s %s %s' % (inspect.stack()[0][3],type(value_),value_)
        add_ = False 
        type_ = type(value_)
        if type_ == str:
            add_ = True
        elif type_ == int:
            add_ = True
            value_ = str(value_)
        elif  type_ == dict:
            extractValuesFromDictionary(results_,value_)
        elif type_ == list:
            extractValuesFromList(results_,value_)
        else:
            print 'Unsupported type %s' % (type(value_))   

        if add_:
            results_.append(value_)


data_ = {'tom':'stats', 'keys':[{'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999},{'mum':'veg', 'nba':'qweqwe'}] }
print data_

separator_ = ','
results_ = []

extractValuesFromDictionary(results_,data_)

print separator_.join(results_)
```

Ouput

python print_out_complicated_structure.py

{'keys': [{'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999}, {'mum': 'veg', 'nba': 'qweqwe'}], 'tom': 'stats'}

extractValuesFromDictionary  [{'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999}, {'mum': 'veg', 'nba': 'qweqwe'}]

extractValuesFromList  {'tim': 'doc', 'year': 1999}

extractValuesFromDictionary  doc

extractValuesFromDictionary  1999

extractValuesFromList  {'mum': 'veg', 'nba': 'qweqwe'}

extractValuesFromDictionary  veg

extractValuesFromDictionary  qweqwe

extractValuesFromDictionary  stats

doc,1999,veg,qweqwe,stats